# Using variables when referring to an objects datamember

Tags: python, django

I'm sort of stuck here. So lets say I have a list of fields (in the context of a DB table):

```
list = ['title', 'description', 'name']
```

These fields exist in the database table Foo.

So here is my issue...

```
foo = Foo()
for i in list:
    foo.i = "value"
foo.save()
```

The issue is that the interpreter is looking for a datamember called `'i'` and is not mapping its value before hand (which would be like, title or description). Is there anyway around this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) built-in function:

```
fields = ['title', 'description', 'name']

foo = Foo()
for field in fields:
    setattr(foo, field, "value")
foo.save()
```

Besides, `list` is not a good variable name - it is shadowing built-in and can cause problems/suprises.

---

Also, you probably want to have a dictionary of "field name: field value" pairs instead. In this case you can [unpack it](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and pass to the model object constructor:

```
fields = {'title': 'My Title', 
          'description': 'My Description', 
          'name': 'My Name'}

foo = Foo(**fields)
foo.save()
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you SO much! Oh and yes, I wouldn't use 'list' in anything but pseudocode.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper you are welcome. Also, check the update after the line, thanks.

Comment: I'm working with '._meta.get_all_field_names()', which is why the keys and values separate. The values are coming from a form. I know ModelForms is the easy solution here, but it will not work with my application.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper ok, if you want - show the code of passing values from the form - sounds like there is still an option to use argument unpacking instead of a loop and `setattr()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set `i` instead of setting name variable of that object.

Please try `setattr` of the object like `setattr(foo,i,value)`